# Are definitelyTyped packages up to date?

Tags: typescript, createjs, definitelytyped, tsd

I can't find any information on how packages are managed. I am looking to use createJS but the lastest commit was a year ago. So it is probably not the current JS version.

I am new to typescript. Not sure I want to proceed if all those good UI lib are not evolving with typescript.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is asking if some software is maintained, which is not a programming question and answers are not likely to be accurate in the future.

Answer (score 3):

> It is a dumb and simple question, but I can't find any information on how packages are managed. I am looking to use createJS but the lastest commit was a year ago... so it is probably not the current js versio

I am a member of the DefinitelyTyped Team. The packages are managed *by the community*. So they are as up to date as the community contributions can be.

Think of it as *really great documentation* maintained *seperately from the original docs by OSS devs*. This should fit your mental model well. In many cases you might find it better than the official docs and in some cases its lagging. For createJS its pretty awesome (from experience).

Comment: The CreateJS team has plans to maintain an updated version of these in a future release, probably later in 2016.

Answer (score 2):

To extend upon [basarat's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34983280/1265447):

As up to date as community contributions can be, given there is a backlog of ~380 Pull Requests currently that are waiting to be merged.